# API works when running script, but not from associated spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

I am trying to apply conditional formatting rules on a google sheet using a google apps script. I found that this could be done with the API, so I enabled it and have it all working when ran from my script ... but when I trigger the script to run from my sheet, the API batchUpdate doesn't run. I am sure I'm missing something simple ...

The code is in the Themes.gs project of this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fs6B-OmlqfoAoon5PcoAYbHq4CO8w0qPqfSRy_OQhe0/copy

specifically this bit doesn't seem to run when the script is triggered from the sheet itself:
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(JSON.stringify(functionname), SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId())

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

1. Rename your `onEdit()` function to something else, like `whenWeEdit()`.
2. Click the link that says: No triggers set up click here to add one now.
3. Under Run, select **whenWeEdit** (or whatever you renamed your function as).
4. Under Events, select **From spreadsheet**.
5. Next, instead of On open, select **On edit**.
6. Click save.
7. Edit the sheet. Your function now seems to work for me. What about you?

Comment: Worked like a charm. I wasn't aware of the difference between simple and installable triggers.

Now that I added this trigger and API code, will users who make a copy be required to click through a bit more hefty of an authorization step?

Comment: Good point. Any user that copies your script will need to authorize the Spreadsheet API. I suggest  that you open an incognito window and paste the link that copies your script. Do it  with another Gmail account that you own. Just so you can see what your users will see ;)

Comment: Yeah, gross. The sheets API has them click through a somewhat scary screen the first time they try to use ANYTHING that is triggered on edit. I applied for OAuth Developer Verification ... how silly.

Comment: Is there some way I can correctly scope my script so it doesn't ask for such ridiculous authorization? It says I want access to view and modify all their drive files, along with all kinds of other outrageous things. All the new code is doing is applying some conditional formatting to the sheet itself.

Comment: (1) [Copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fs6B-OmlqfoAoon5PcoAYbHq4CO8w0qPqfSRy_OQhe0/copy) your Spreadsheet yourself. (2) Install the **On edit** trigger. (3) Test the new copy in an incognito window the first few times. (4) Send to a user, you are done. (5) If you have too many users, you can probably automate steps 1-4 by installing and [managing triggers programatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically), though I never tried. (6) If my answer fits your needs, please consider upvoting it.